# Using Image field for SQL search

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Access database table which includes an field for a file attachment for an image. How can I create a SQL query to search for NULL value in this field? I have used

```
SELECT * FROM [Student Register]
  WHERE ((([Student Register].Image.FileName)="isnull"));
```

but this just brings up an empty result table.
Thanks
Sara

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Column_Name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to try something along the lines of:

`SELECT * FROM [Student Register]
  WHERE Image.FileName Is Null;`

Comment: Thank you this worked a treat - I'm to reliant on the Wizard methinks!

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working now! Would you mind accepting this answer to resolve your question?